# Is there a good forum out there discussing iCalendar format and interoperability?

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I can't seem to find a good forum focusing on iCalendar format. Specifically how iCalendar is implemented with Outlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are producing iCalendar data and want to check for problems with Outlook then you could try validating it with [Douglas Day's validator](http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/).

His validator not only measures your iCalendar data against the RFC 5545 specification but also advises of potential compatibility issues.

The validator is based on DDay.iCal which aims "at being as RFC 5545 compliant as possible, while targeting compatibility with popular calendaring applications, like Apple iCal, Outlook 2007, etc.".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is usually to try it. Of course, that means installing Outlook or having a friend/user you can work with who does.  I realise this is often a problem, but it's really the only way to know for sure how an application will behave.

On the interop side: if you get it working in Apple Mail/iCal, GMail, and Outlook, you should be pretty good with other mailers too, from my experience.